# Minecraft ERRCONNECT MINEFLAYER ERROR Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:25595

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, minecraft, mineflayer

I am Recieving this errror when i run this simple code snippet

```
import mineflayer from 'mineflayer';

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 25595,
  username: 'Maaz_Bot', // minecraft username
  password:''
})
```

I was expecting it to join the localhost server which is hosted at port 25595 by using lan world and mineflayer library

Comment: How are you running the server? Perhaps it's only bound to `127.0.0.1:25595` (IPv4)

Answer (score 0):

Try using new port , By quitting the world an rejoining the world again

Answer (score -2):

Try importing mineflayer like below and also you can handle the events using, on login and on error

```
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 25595,
  username: 'Maaz_Bot', // minecraft username
  password: '',
});

bot.on('login', () => {
  console.log('Bot has logged in');
});

bot.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error:', err);
});
```

For more info please go through documentation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mineflayer

Comment: Welcome on SO. This doesn't answer to the question